# How to add vanilla JS via useEffect to my React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to wrap my head around adding this vanilla carousel-like library: https://github.com/NickPiscitelli/Glider.js to my React project. It's very [lightweight](https://nickpiscitelli.github.io/Glider.js/) and smooth like butter.

It does not require a lot of code to implement. Only a `<Link>` and `<Script>` to get the party started.
I'd like to use React-Helmet to handle the link and script tags.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1/glider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1/glider.min.css">
```

This is how you initialize the glider: `new Glider(document.querySelector('.glider'));`

I read that I can use `useEffect` hook to do that for me. I've tried my best to use this library in React but I encounter this problem:

```
Cannot read property '_glider' of null
```

Inside my useEffect?

I've added a sandbox to reproduce the problem,

https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-platform-d8me2

How can I implement this library of simple vanilla JS to a modern React web-app and get everything working?

Comment: The sandbox doesn't have any code attempting a solution? Have you considered using refs?

Comment: Please try now, apologies.

Comment: Apparently there is a react port of that library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-glider. Why not use that?

Comment: Two reasons, it might be an abandoned library and i don’t know how to use typescript.

Comment: "Updated 4 months ago" is abandoned? What makes you think you need to know typescript to use it?

Comment: The docs only show examples in typescript, which I do not know how to use. The last merge has failed? I would rather try to implement and understand how to use the vanilla library into my own project.

Comment: Ok I won't try and convince you to use something you're not comfortable with. In your example the ref is not being used. The ref should be what is passed to the Glider. Are you familiar with using refs in react?

Comment: Thank you for understanding. I’m actually not to familiar, could you show me how I could fix the code by using ref properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const scriptLink = document.createElement('script');
        scriptLink.async = true;
        scriptLink.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1/glider.min.js';
        document.body.appendChild(scriptLink);

    // you can also create and append a link element

        const scriptCode = document.createElement('script');

        const code = "let glider = new Glider(document.querySelector('.glider'));";
        let inlineCode = document.createTextNode(code);
        scriptCode.appendChild(inlineCode);
        document.body.appendChild(scriptCode);          

    }, []);
```